# How to disable button(or whole main window) in PyQt4 until the function returns 0

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have one web scraper script, let' call it scraper.py, that writes data to a database. I have made gui with tableWidget that displays database contents. Now, I have added a button that will call main() function from the scraper.py script. Since, scraper is using selenium and is taking about 20 seconds to finish everything(from opening browser and closing it) I want that button to be disabled (or perhaps whole form named MainWindow) until scraper.py finishes.
Also, main() function doesn't necessarily need to have a 'return 0' statement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fetchFuction():
    QtGui.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor))
    # if incase function failed then restore it
    try:
        yourFetchFucn()
        QtGui.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
    except:
        QtGui.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, that could work too. I found another way and that is..when the button is clicked, first it becomes disabled, a function main() is called, after that it becomes enabled. simple as that